# browsersync reloads page in chrome, but doesn't show the changes

Tags: browser-sync

In my gulp task I use browsersync, but since a while chrome doesn't refresh the css. I use browsersync with Safari and Chrome. In the past everything was fine, I didn't changed the gulp settings. In Safari the reload works like expected, in Chrome I can see the page reload, also the «Connected to BrowserSync» Message in the top right corner. After browsersync was reloading chrome, nothing happend. To see the changes I have to manually «shift reload» chrome. I reseted chrome to the basic settings, I found also a post were someone said I have to disable the «browser cache» in the DevTools under Network. Finally I added firefox to the browser tag, and also in firefox everything is fine.

I have a fresh macOS Sierra (10.12.6) running with all the newest browser versions.

Attached my gulpfile.js

> ```
> // VARIABLES
> // ********************************************************
>
> var gulp           = require('gulp'),
>     browserSync    = require('browser-sync'),
>     del            = require('del'),
>     autoprefixer   = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
>     notify         = require('gulp-notify'),
>     plumber        = require('gulp-plumber'),
>     sass           = require('gulp-sass'),
>     sassGlob       = require('gulp-sass-glob'),
>     sourcemaps     = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
>     runSequence    = require('run-sequence');
>
>
>
>
> // Functions
> // ********************************************************
>
> // Plumber Function zur Ausgabe von Fehlermeldungen
> function customPlumber(errTitle) {
>   return plumber({
>     errorHandler: notify.onError({
>       title: errTitle || "Error running Gulp",
>       message: "Error: <%= error.message %>",
>       sound: "Glass",
>     })
>   })
> }
>
>
>
>
> // Tasks
> // ********************************************************
>
>
>
> // Sass kompilieren ---------
> gulp.task('sass', function() {
>   return gulp.src('../themes/custom/my-website/sass/**/*.scss')
>     .pipe(customPlumber('Error Running Sass'))
>     .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
>     .pipe(sassGlob())
>     .pipe(sass({
>       includePaths: ['bower_components'],
>     }))
>     .pipe(autoprefixer({
>       browsers: 'last 2 versions',
>     }))
>     .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./sourcemap'))
>     .pipe(gulp.dest('../themes/custom/my-website/css'))
>     .on('end', browserSync.reload);
> });
>
>
> // Browser Sync (Proxy)------
> gulp.task('browserSync', function() {
>   browserSync({
>     proxy: 'dev-my-website.selfip.net',
>     browser: ['google chrome', 'safari', 'firefox'],
>   });
> });
>
>
> // Clean --------------------
> gulp.task('clean:dev', function() {
>   del([
>     'css'
>   ]);
> });
>
>
> // Watch --------------------
> gulp.task('watch', function() {
>   gulp.watch('../themes/custom/my-website/sass/**/*.scss',['sass']);
>   gulp.watch('../themes/custom/my-website/templates/**/*.twig', browserSync.reload);
> });
>
>
> // Default Task -------------
> gulp.task('default', function(callback) {
>   runSequence(
>     'clean:dev',
>     'sass',
>     ['browserSync', 'watch'],
>     callback
>   )
> });
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using sourcemaps, so your problem could very well be [an SSL certificate issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40261854/435004).